# How can I make a window stay on Top using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to make a given window e.g. notepad or any other window to stay on top?

Please note this is not a question on how to make a `Form` or a `WPF` window stay on Top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use interop for this,

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

to toggle always on top, and

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

to deactivate.

courtesy of https://github.com/oazabir/AlwaysOnTop

Comment: Exactly what I needed, tnx :-)